# Bunifu controls not autoscaling

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bunifu

Bunifu controls don't scale properly on display's with different resolutions. Is scaling not supported on Bunifu controls or is there a setting to fix that?

[image: Broken button]

Comment: Is your app DpiAware? -- You need to specify the .Net version in use.

Comment: I am using .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: So, you mean that your app is not DpiAware? Do you know what that means? -- Anyway, in `app.config`, add `<System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection><add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2" /><add key="EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing" value="false" /></System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>` (in 4 lines). Also, read here: [Windows Forms Add Configuration Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/winforms/windows-forms-add-configuration-element) -- I suggest to upgrade to .Net Framework 4.8.

Comment: I haven't manually mentioned the Winforms app to be DpiAware. If Winform apps are DpiAware by default, then it is else not.

Comment: WinForms apps that target .Net 6+ are DpiAware. Since you're targeting .Net Framework, your app is not DpiAware unless you opt-in. Read my previous comment (and the documentation. This one also: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms)).